# Comprobar checkbox marcaados con un atributo similar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo una pequeña duda.

Quiero saber como hago para impedir que un checkbox se pueda marcar cuando hay otro checkbox marcado con una caracteristica similar.

Por ejemplo:
Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<td>
<label for="check1"> Valor1
<input id="check1" type="checkbox" serial="1324"  />
</label>
<label for="check2"> Valor2
<input id="check2" type="checkbox" serial="1324"  />
</label>
</td>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que si por ejemplo yo tengo el #check1 marcado, me muestre una alerta al intentar marcar el #check2 ya que tiene el mismo serial que el #check1

La forma en que estoy haciendolo ahora es con el siguiente codigo :

```
$(this).closest("td").find(":checkbox:not(:checked)").prop("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));
```

Que lo que hace es que me deshabilita el siguiente checkbox dentro del  pero no me funciona de manera optima ya que pueden haber otros inputs dentro del mismo

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Siempre va ser por ese atributo o puede haber otro atributo??

Comment: Siempre el mismo atributo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta lo siguiente:

```
var $this = $(this);
var prop = $this.attr('serial');
$this.closest("td").find(":checkbox:not(:checked)[serial="+prop+"]").prop("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));
```

Si deseas mostrar una alerta si ya existe uno marcado con el mismo serial, puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
var $this = $(this);
var prop = $this.attr('serial');
var marcadoYa = $this.closest("td").find(":checkbox:checked[serial="+prop+"]").length;
if (marcadoYa) {
   alert('Ya se ha seleccionado otra opción con el serial: '+prop);
   $this.prop('checked', false);
}
```

Comment: Bro, funciona perfecto, aunque me gustaria es que el sistema me muestre una alerta diciendome que no puedo seleccionar ese checkbox porque ya tengo el otro marcado!. Eres un crack!

Comment: Jajja gracias dejame pensar una solución para esto ultimo

Comment: Mira ver edite la respuesta a ver si la segunda opción se adapta a lo ke estabas buscando